# Spring Boot JSP application without defining controllers

Tags: jsp, spring-boot, migration

I am migrating an existing jsp application to spring boot.  I have run through the standard hello world examples that frankly are not setup to scale very well (IMO).  In the [spring boot example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-jsp) a controller is defined to take the default path and route you to the hello.jsp.  Scaling this out means that every jsp will have to have its own controller requestMapping - not desirable.  So I went ahead and created a method method for mapping all JSPs

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
String home() {
    Logger.info("Routing to the home page")
    return "home"
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/{file:.+}")
String jspMapper(@PathVariable String file) {
    Logger.info("Routing to the $file page (generically)")
    return file
}
```

Now this "works", however it means that all existing jsps will need to have their links changed from something like:

```
<a href="home.jsp">Home</a>
```

to:

```
<a href="home">Home</a>
```

Furthermore all assets such as .js, .html, .css, .png, etc. are not working co-mingled into the jsps (sub dirs are used of course).  I know I can add a static folder under the resources, but that also requires changes to the references in the JSP (as I understand it).

**Is there a way to just have all requests (of which I did not register a servlet to match to) routed to the webapp folder (in my case WEB-INF/jsp)? I would like to minimize the changes to the jsps if possible.**

Gradle snippits for environment information:

```
ext {
    springBootVersion = '1.5.2.RELEASE'
}

apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'groovy'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat')
    compile('javax.servlet:jstl')
    compile('org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper')
    compile('org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler:ecj:4.6.1')
    compile('org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all')
```

Comment: In modern web development, every request should go through a controller because the logic for the request should be (nearly) non-existent in the view. So this actually does scale quite well. You're dealing with a legacy application where best practices have evolved since then. You're solution seems viable if you want to keep all your logic in the JSP files. But I'd encourage you to move them into controllers/services while you're migrating.

Comment: In modern web development, I probably would not be using jsps.  These controllers are quite simple and building them seems quite pointless and actually feels like quite a bit of ceremony I don't want to perform.

Comment: Why would you need that... You already have something that works now, just port that. Resources under `WEB-INF` aren't directly accessible so you need to have something, apparently you currently have something for that in place just use that.